# MYSQL is inserting more than one row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using MYSQL in my PHP project and I'm having a "strange" (not sure if I'm ignorant or what) with the following query:

```
public function vote($user) {

    $this->DB->prepare('INSERT INTO Ratings (Entry_ID, Rating, User) VALUES (:entry_id, :rating, :user);');
    $this->DB->bind(':entry_id', $this->getID(), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $this->DB->bind(':rating', 1, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $this->DB->bind(':user', $user);
    $this->DB->execute();
    $this->votes++;
}
```

Into the following table:

```
// Ratings table
$DB->prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ratings ("
            ."  Entry_ID int(11),"
            ."  ID int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            ."  Rating int(11),"
            ."  User varchar(255),"
            ."  PRIMARY KEY (ID),"
            ."  FOREIGN KEY (User) REFERENCES Users(Username)"
            ."  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,"
            ."  FOREIGN KEY (Entry_ID) REFERENCES Entries(Entry_ID)"
            ."  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE"
            .") CHARACTER SET utf8;");
$DB->execute();
```

The previous table is being used to store every vote the users cast.

Problem is that every time I execute the first query (the `INSERT`) more than one row is being created in the `Ratings` table.

**Edit**: The vote function is called inside an ajax response script:

```
session_start();

$entry = new Entry();

switch(filter_var($_POST["action"])){

    // Create Entry
    case "create":
        break;

    // Delete entry
    case "delete":
        break;

    // Rate entry
    case "rate":

        $entry->load($entry->decryptID(filter_var($_POST["entryId"])));
        $validator = new Validator();

        if($validator->checkRating(filter_var($_POST["rating"]), $entry->getEncryptedID(), filter_var($_SESSION["User"]))) {

            $entry->vote($_SESSION['User']);
            die();
            $entry->save();

            echo "OK";
        } else {

            echo "ERROR";
        }
        break;

    default: 

        echo "ERROR";
        break;   
}
```

Comment: can u post the complete code ?

Comment: is it in some kind of loop? post complete code

Comment: Note on the `CREATE TABLE`-- you don't need to `prepare()/execute()` if there is no user input that needs to be inserted. That can just be executed in `$DB->query("CREATE TABLE....")`

Comment: When 2 rows are inserted it is generally because the code is called twice and you didn't realize it. That can be due to logic problems in the code, but can also be due to things like empty `src=""` attributes on `<img>` tags (or similar) in your HTML.

Comment: Now that we know this is wrapped in a `vote()` function, please post where you _call_ the function.

Comment: If you're executing this in a browser, open up the network console and watch it while it runs. Does this script get called twice, due perhaps to a faulty AJAX request, or an otherwise empty HTTP call (which goes to the same URI as the parent page)>

Comment: The AJAX script responses only once when i press the upvote button, therefore it's not in a loop.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I found out that the problem is in the `load()` function, where the `vote()` is being called mistakenly. Your comment was very helpful, thanks.